# How do I autohide a form

Tags: c#, timer, thread-sleep

I have a very simple question i guess...for which i am not able to find an answer for. I am trying to add an autohide feature for a borderless WinForm which is located at (0,0) with a width of 150. I have the following code:

```
    private int dx;

    private void autohide()
    {
        for (dx = 0; dx > -150; dx--)
        {
            this.Width = dx;
            Thread.Sleep(2);
        }
    }
```

Even after, using `Thread.Sleep(x)`, the Form just snaps off to final Width without giving/having any effect of delay. I am trying to put a bit of effect on to it .

Please help...

Comment: You should read the documentation for `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: sleeping for 2 milliseconds won't give you anywhere near long enough to see something happen. Im curious as to why you are trying to do this rather than just `Hide` the form though

Comment: it's probably because you are doing it in the main thread, i.e. the same thread that is updating your form. Is this WinForms? WPF?

Comment: `Application.DoEvents` (ugh) ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because the window is not re-drawing itself at any point because your code doesn't exit the autohide() routine until dx is 150, so it will just have a delay before re-drawing in the final position.

You probably also want to change the position rather than the width.

The better option would be to start up a Timer which then changes the position each time it fires, which would cause the change to be animated:

```
    private Timer t;
    private int step = 1;

    private void autohide()
    {
        t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 2;
        t.Tick += T_Tick;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Location.X > 0 - this.Width)
        {
            this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X - step, this.Location.Y);
        }
        else
        {
            t.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to make sure, is this allowed? I'm thinking that `Location` may only be changed from the UI thread. Wouldn't this be modified from a background thread?

Comment: With the correct Timer (there are three, System.Windows.Forms.Timer, System.Threading.Timer and System.Timers.Timer) it would ensure that it runs on the UI thread. System.Windows.Forms.Timer calls back on the UI thread. There are issues to using this timer if the UI thread is busy, but I don't think that'd matter here.